# Do derived classes inherit differently?

Tags: c#, casting, derived-class

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.UI.TableHeaderCell
```

derives from

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.UI.TableCell
```

So a method with the signature `foo(TableCell tc){}`

Will accept instances of TableHeaderCell.

However if i create two new classes and derive one from `TableCell` and the other from `TableHeaderCell` then my new TableHeaderCell class will obviously not be able to cast into my new TableCell class as they are not directly related.

Is there anyway to get around this? Im guessing no.

Comment: While it's "obvious" that what you say is true (see Jon's diagram), this is not because "Derived classes inherit differently". It is simply because C# doesn't have multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

You mean a hierarchy like this?

```
                  TableCell
                 /         \
                /           \
        TableHeaderCell   CustomTableCell
              /
             /                
  CustomTableHeaderCell
```

No, in that case you couldn't cast `CustomTableHeaderCell` to `CustomTableCell`.

Are you sure you really need inheritance in this case? Could you use composition instead? Or could you make `CustomTableCell` and `CustomTableHeaderCell` implement an `ICustomCell` interface? If you could give us more information about what you're trying to do, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

You could just keep referring to all of them as TableCell objects, at least if the goal is to be able to call your foo().